# Does max_workers argument in ProcessPoolExecutor represent the no.of cores in the CPU?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm currently using ProcessPoolExecutor to parallely run multiple forecasting models. I have a 4core 16gb RAM config. Is the max_workers argument represent the number of cores in the CPU? If don't intend on using all the cores can I set max_workers = 3??

Comment: If you want to check this, (if you runing on Windows) you can check this simply by locking on environment variable: NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS. just type env in a command prompt and you will see the variable value

Comment: You have one more method to check this via psutil module in python.
in your script import psutil and check the logical cores and the physical cores num and do the comparison,
you acheive this by calling to this method from psutil: psutil.cpu_count()

Comment: ***Is the max_workers ... the number of cores***: **No**, it's the max number of started processes. Python don't control how much and which core is assigned to a particular process. It's possible that all your processes are using only one core.